# Redirect to 404 or 403?

Tags: 6, blocks

When you set the 404/403 error pages to nodes with a path, how then can you have Drupal go to the 404 path or 403 path instead of outputting the message on the page?

For example, if I type in www.mydomain.com/skdjhfjsdhfjsh, it shows the custom 404 text from my node. But, is there a way to make Drupal send the user to www.mydomain.com/404, so I can use Contexts/Blocks with in the content area of this specific page?

Comment: Redirecting 403 or 404 errors is not a good idea.  You want the 403 or 404 to be associated with the URL that the user requested.  When you redirect, you need to generate a 301 or a 302 so that is what is getting associated with the URL.  The 403 or 404 error would be associated only with the page you redirected to.

Comment: So essentially, there is no way to add blocks to 404/403 errors at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that redirecting a 404 page is a bad idea.  One way customize error pages is the [blocks404](http://drupal.org/project/blocks404) module.

Answer (score 3):

Another method for showing blocks is possible with [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels).

You can configure Drupal to display a node for a 403 and/or 404.  You can then configure your node view panel template appropriately.  What I don't recall us being able to use the error code in play to use as visibility rules for pane content.

Answer (score 0):

The [Custom Error](http://drupal.org/project/customerror) module lets you set up custom 403 and 404 error pages.  You can also do custom redirects for 404.

Disclosure: I am the co-maintainer for Custom Error.